# Prevent bundler from upgrading gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I'm working on a project and we've just updated bundler to version 1.7.0.  There was a few days of trouble in getting all the gemfiles/gemfile.locks in a correct state, but I'm still having trouble with one issue in particular.

If there are differences in `Gemfile.lock`, I check it out, and then bundle so that I will have the gems in the `Gemfile`.  However bundle seems to always auto-upgrade my gems.  For example:

```
Installing multi_json 1.10.1 (was 1.9.2)
```

The rest of my team is using 1.9.2 - there's a dependency in another part of the application or...who knows.  I should be using 1.9.2, but bundler consistently 'auto-upgrades' everytime i run bundle.  Is there a way to prevent this behavior? I'm using RVM 1.25.23

Comment: Do you have a specific version of the gem defined in your Gemfile?

Comment: @koffeinfrei, no.  I'm not looking for specific versions, per se, what i want is for gems that are already present to be left alone (not upgraded)

Comment: What I was asking was if you have your gem locked to a specific version in your Gemfile, e.g. `gem 'multi_json', '1.10.1'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bundler 1.7.0 has some bugs which can result in unexpected gem updates. Please try upgrading to the latest version (1.7.2 at the time that I write this).

See:

- https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3136
- https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3142
- https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3149

Answer (score 0):

Try:

bundle install --frozen

This should p[revent bundler to update the Gemfile.lock](http://bundler.io/v1.1/bundle_install.html).